# Ebay Selling APIs seems not to work in production environment

Tags: e-commerce, ebay-api

I'm new to eBay APIs. I want to create a tool that can modify listings on my eBay selling account. So I got a user token by hitting the button in the image and sign in into my eBay selling account:

[image]

Then I pasted my user token into the API Explorer to test things out. The return code is 200(Okay) but existing listings number I got is 0 while the my inventory on my selling account has over 100 listings. Any ideas how to fix this? I really appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a support issue, not a programming question (so... off-topic here). Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)